# Create-nuxt-app creates nuxt with 2.0.0 even if it's 2.8.0

Tags: nuxt.js

I have an issue with installing nuxt.

The thing is,`yarn global list` shows

```
info "create-nuxt-app@2.8.0" has binaries:
      - create-nuxt-app
```

After running `yarn create nuxt-app` I check my package.json which shows `"nuxt": "^2.0.0"`

Why so? I checked that the latest nuxt version is 2.8.1, shouldn't it be 2.8.1 in package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different packages at play here. First we have `create-nuxt-app`, which scaffolds your project and is at version 2.8.0.

That scaffold contains the `package.json` [template](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/blob/master/template/_package.json#L101), which is used to generate the `package.json` of *your* project. It contains `"nuxt": "^2.0.0"`, where the `^` means: "Get me the latest minor version (and patch version) of nuxt 2", which as time of writing is `2.8.1`. See also [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

In conclusion, there is no need to update that template file everytime a new nuxt version is released, you'll always get the latest `2.x.x` version of nuxt.

Comment: Does it mean that after scaffolding my nuxtjs project I'll need to update nuxt version manually since I get 2.0.0 which is written in create-nuxt-app package.json template?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that, as you get the latest version beginning with 2.x.x, which is 2.8.1. Note that the caret symbol `^` is the important part. If it were just `2.0.0` without the `^`, then you would get only the version `2.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I swear I knew this :)